# Hibernate - reusable component definition in XML?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, jpa-2.0

Is it possible to have reusable component definition in XML like pair `@Embeddable` and `@Embedded` ?

I've a complex component mapping and have to use it 10+ times throw XML mapping (yes, I know hot to copy mapping, but hope for a better solution). Unfortunately can't use annotations ...

Answer (score 0):

Please be more specific as to what you trying to do?

If you are asking if the attributes of a component can be mapped to different columns then as per the documentation - and verified by you - you can do this:

```
@Embedded
@AttributeOverrides( {

        @AttributeOverride(name="iso2", column = @Column(name="bornIso2") ),

        @AttributeOverride(name="name", column = @Column(name="bornCountryName") )

} )
Country bornIn;
```

This will map the iso2 field in Country class to bornIso2 and name to bornCountryName. Hope this helps

Comment: I know how it works for annotation. I need similar for XML mapping.

Comment: In xml configuration you can use the <component> tag that corresponds to Emeddable. If you want to reuse one xml (reuse <component> definition) in another you could try using the xInclude tag, but I haven't tried this.
    <xi:include href="some-component.xml" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"/>